# Drawing MultiPolygon with different style for each component in OpenLayers

Tags: vector, coding-style, polygon, openlayers

I have a OpenLayers.Feature.Vector created as follows:

```
var multiPol = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon([polygonGeometry1,polygonGeometry2]));
```

Both polygons represent same logical object (an "entity") on a map, say a cloud. This is why I keep them in one feature.
I would like to draw it so that each component of this multi-polygon (polygonGeometry1, polygonGeometry2) is drawn with different color when it's added to a layer:

```
   var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("polygonLayer");
   layer.addFeatures([multiPol]);
```

I have taken a look at styles, style maps and rules in OpenLayers but they appear to be insufficient. They do enable me to draw each geometry type with different color but only if they belong to different features (vectors). Is there a way to solve this problem? Do really I have to use separate Vector for each polygon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, to get this functionality you will need to extend the classes with your own.

First create an extension to OpenLayers.Feature.Vector, name it YourApp.Feature.MultiVector.  You can see examples on how to extend classes by looking at the OpenLayers code. This class should accept an array of styles and the multiPolygon.  It should have a method that will return a list of OpenLayers.Feature.Vectors each with their own style.

Second create an extension to OpenLayers.Layer.Vector, name it YourApp.Layer.VectorSupportingMultiStyledFeatures.  You will need to override the "drawFeature" method.  In the drawFeature method test to see if the type of the feature is a MultiVector.  If it is, loop through each feature in the MultiVector and call renderer.drawFeature(feature).  Otherwise call the super.drawFeature method.

So your code to call it would look like this:

```
var multiPol = new YourApp.Feature.MultiVector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon([polygonGeometry1,polygonGeometry2]),
    [style1,style2,style3,style4]);

var layer = new YourApp.Layer.VectorSupportingMultiStyledFeatures("polygonLayer");
layer.addFeatures([multiPol]);
```

Comment: I was about to do something like this but just wanted to make sure there is no simpler and less work consuming solution. Thanks!

Comment: I have implemented a CompositeVector class that holds a set of vectors, each vector having it's own geometry and optionally style. I also needed a special OpenLayers.Layer.Vector implementation that supports these. To sum up: it worked :)

Comment: Sorry to bring up such an old thread, but I'm currently trying to achieve the same (with OpenLayers 2.12) but ran into a Problem: I implemented a Multi (or Composite) Vector, which basically has multiple features, but is a feature itself. I rewrote the drawFeature method in Layer.Vector as suggested, but now I have strange behavior: The features get drawn correctly, but when the viewport gets resized, the features get drawn twice. I think it all comes down to having features that have features themselves. Is there something else I have to rewrite, something I should not forget?

Answer (score 3):

The proposed solution by Jon Snyder provided us with a general idea, but did not fully work for in the end (especially extending `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector` wasn't necessary for this task, based on OpenLayers 2.1x).

We created a class `YourApp.Handler.EndPointsPath` (extending `OpenLayers.Handler.Path`), where the function `geometryClone()` returns a new geometry of type `YourApp.Geometry.EndPointsPath`.

We then patched the function `drawGeometry()` in `OpenLayers.Renderer.Elements` to draw this new geometry:

```
OpenLayers.Util.extend(OpenLayers.Renderer.Elements.prototype, {

  drawGeometry: function (geometry, style, featureId) {
    var cl = geometry.CLASS_NAME;

    var rendered = true,
      i, len;
    if ((cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection") ||
      (cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPoint") ||
      (cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiLineString") ||
      (cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon") ||
      (cl === "YourApp.Geometry.EndPointsPath")) {
      // Iterate over all Geometry components and draw each individually
      for (i = 0, len = geometry.components.length; i < len; i++) {
        // Is there a style for each of the components?
        if (OpenLayers.Util.isArray(style)) {
          // Draw Geometry with own style
          rendered = this.drawGeometry(geometry.components[i], style[i], featureId) && rendered;
        } else {
          // Draw Geometry with common style 
          rendered = this.drawGeometry(geometry.components[i], style, featureId) && rendered;
        }
      }
      return rendered;
    }
    // (...standard code...)
  },

  eraseGeometry: function (geometry, featureId) {
    var cl = geometry.CLASS_NAME,
      i, len;
    if ((cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPoint") ||
      (cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiLineString") ||
      (cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPolygon") ||
      (cl === "YourApp.Geometry.EndPointsPath") ||
      (cl === "OpenLayers.Geometry.Collection")) {
      for (i = 0, len = geometry.components.length; i < len; i++) {
        this.eraseGeometry(geometry.components[i], featureId);
      }
      // (...standard code...)
    }
  }
});
```